# Pillow - OSError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have a script that scraping images with related keywords on google and then process them with pillow.

But when i try with multiple keywords pillows gives a error :

`OSError: cannot identify image file`

I try to solve with

`ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True`

but still I got the same error. Why this is happens and how can I solve this ?

Comment: Please attempt to include a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: maybe the spaces are causing problems. try adding " symbols like: "image name with spaces"

Comment: Kindly show your code that is having problems and a sample of an *"unhappy"* image.